# Jasmine JSCover no instrument does not work

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, command, jasmine, jscoverage

I must be missing something here. I have Jasmine test and I am looking to check what coverage that test has on `onTheMove-Tree.js` file.
I am using [default example server setup](http://jscover.sourceforge.net/manual/manual.xml) server runs on `http://localhost:8080/jscoverage.html?/index.html.`
I have modified index.html file to include dependencies (code at the bottom of post) that I have placed in `\doc\example\dependencies` in same folder is my Jasmine test file `'jasmine-OnTheMove-OnTheMove_ObjectTreeStructure-Tests.js'`.
File that I intend to get test coverage for `onTheMove-Tree.js` is in `doc\example` directory in the same directory that `index.html` is. I am starting server with following command:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\JSCover-0.2.0>java -jar target/dist/JSCover-all
.jar -ws --branch --document-root=doc/example --no-instrument=doc/example/depend
encies
```

However I can see files in dependencies folder being modified (check screenshot), this then results in all tests failing (same screenshot). **Why is JSCover instrumenting files in `\doc\example\dependencies`?**
[image]

Index.html code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<title>JavaScript Tests</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onTheMoveTest = {};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/dependencies/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dependencies/ua-parser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dependencies/knockout-3.0.0.custom.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dependencies/knockout.validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="onTheMove-Tree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dependencies/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dependencies/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dependencies/jasmine-jquery-1.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dependencies/jasmine-OnTheMove-OnTheMove_ObjectTreeStructure-Tests.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {

        "use strict";

        var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
        jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 250;

        var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
        jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);

        jasmineEnv.specFilter = function (spec) {
            return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
        };

        var currentWindowOnload = window.onload;
        window.onload = function () {
            if (currentWindowOnload) {
                currentWindowOnload();
            }

            execJasmine();
        };

        function execJasmine() {
            jasmineEnv.execute();
        }

    })();
</script>
</head>
<body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--no-instrument=URL` is URL path based, not file-system based, so you need `--no-instrument=/dependencies`